# What happens when using push(), offer() and add() methods in ArrayDeque at the same time?

Tags: java, collections, arraydeque

`ArrayDeque` has methods for stacks and queues. Mostly used stack and queue methods are the ones in the below:

`Stack` methods: `push`/`poll`/`peek`

`Queue` methods: `push`/`poll`/`peek`

The thing that I've done in the below code block is that, I tried to understand behavior of the `ArrayDeque` when both offer, push and add methods are used in the same object. The code that I wrote and its output is given below. What is the behavior of the `ArrayDeque` after calling `push()` method, which it assumes itself as a stack, and then calling the `offer()` method, which is stated as queue methods.

```
Deque<Integer> arrayDeque = new ArrayDeque<>(); 

arrayDeque.add(3);
arrayDeque.push(4);
arrayDeque.offer(6);
arrayDeque.addFirst(2);
arrayDeque.addLast(5);
arrayDeque.addFirst(1);
System.out.println("ArrayDeque: " + arrayDeque.toString());
```

The output is:

```
ArrayDeque: [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Comment: What is strange here?

Comment: Read the javadoc. What all these methods do is clearly explained there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what it does step by step

```
// Add 3 at the tail of this deque
arrayDeque.add(3); -> [3]
// Add 4 at the head of this deque
arrayDeque.push(4); -> [4, 3]
// Add 6 at the tail of this deque
arrayDeque.offer(6); -> [4, 3, 6]
// Add 2 at the head of this deque
arrayDeque.addFirst(2); -> [2, 4, 3, 6]
// Add 5 at the tail of this deque
arrayDeque.addLast(5); -> [2, 4, 3, 6, 5]
// Add 1 at the head of this deque
arrayDeque.addFirst(1); -> [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Keep in mind that the main purpose of a `Deque` unlike a `Queue` or a `Stack` is to have the ability to access/add the elements **at/to both** ends (head and tail).

Comment: Basically this  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

Answer (score 0):

1.offer-This method inserts the specified element at the end of this deque.
2.add-This method inserts the specified element at the end of this deque.
3.push-This method pushes an element onto the stack represented by this deque.
4.addFirst-This method inserts the specified element at the front of this deque.
5.addLast-This method inserts the specified element at the end of this deque.

Answer (score 0):

What don't you understand?

> Could you explain the behaviour of the ArrayDeque after calling push() method, which it assumes itself as a stack, and then calling the offer() method, which is stated as queue methods in the JavaDoc

Take a look at the Javadoc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

`push` method insert at the beginning and `offer` insert at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Nicolas Filotto answer is right. 
I found out the "tail" explanation in source code file is wrong. It says add=push. However, in function implementation, add = addLast, push = addFirst.
[image]